# How do I prevent directory listing in Jetty?

Tags: java, jetty, block

Basically I have this jetty server running at my local with a bunch of folder/files right under the root directory webapp/.
Currently they can be accessed just by typing http://localhost:8080/server-name/ in the browser like this:

[image: the static directory of the server]

Obviously it looks very ugly when users goes to this root directory so I'm wondering if it is possible to block this page or mask it with some friendly message.

So far I've come to this method by adding security-constraint in web.xml:

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>precluded methods</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/font/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/libs/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/mock/*</url-pattern>          
        <url-pattern>/modules/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/subpage/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/util/*</url-pattern>          
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

But apparently it would block the actual access to above jsp/folders from users and that is certainly not what I intended. 
So is it possible to simply block/mask the page from users without any other affects?

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to edit your `web.xml`?

In case positive, add this snippet

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
  <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Note: that snippet belongs to the default servlet configuration.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, yes you're right. I forgot to mention. OP, keep this information in mind.

Comment: thanks both for the tips. So I'm sensing the servlet class I'm using 
org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
is not capable of using this para right? I looked through the api and no field named dirAllowed found...

Comment: Try to repalce `dirAllowed` for `listings`,

Answer (score 0):

Like  @josivan & @Joakim said all I need to do is to add a default servlet and set the flag to false

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Posting the detailed answer here.